# How to write the json for patch on Django REST Framework

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework

I have `PATCH` button form on `ModelViewSet`

[image]

```
class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = s.CompanySerializer   
    queryset = m.Company.objects.all()
    def patch(self, request, id, format=None):
        print(id)
```

Now I try to modify the existing data id = 1

So I write this in textarea and push `PATCH` button.

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name": ""
}
```

However , there comes error like

`patch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'`

Maybe my json is wrong?? How can I do PATCH?

patch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Answer (score 1):

Use `perform_update` like this :

```
class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = s.CompanySerializer   
queryset = m.Company.objects.all() 

def perform_update(self, serializer):
    instance = serializer.instance
    request = self.request
    serializer.save(**modified_attrs)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: THank you I use `perfome_update`. however somehow it doesn't work ,but use `update` instead. it works.